# The Ark of God carried by oxen

Tags: ark-of-the-covenant

If the ark was supposed to be carried by the Levites, Why does it state that the oxen carried  the Ark of God in 2 Samuel 6:1-10?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Which passage are you discussing?

Comment: It is expected on the Stack Exchange platform that questions will be researched and supported by substantiated references. Please add clarity and detail to your question so that it can be sensibly addressed.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you are correct ,The  Ark was to be carried by the levites , and not to be carried by oxen or on a cart, yet scripture shows an example of just that ......however it was wrong to do so and it cost a man his life .

Notice v 9 of Numbers 7

Num 7:6  So Moses took the wagons and the oxen and gave them to the Levites. 
Num 7:7  Two wagons and four oxen he gave to the sons of Gershon, according to their service. 
Num 7:8  And four wagons and eight oxen he gave to the sons of Merari, according to their service, under the direction of Ithamar the son of Aaron the priest. 
**Num 7:9  But to the sons of Kohath he gave none, because they were charged with the service of the holy things that had to be carried on the shoulder**.

Yet In Chronicles we see that yes indeed the Ark was being carried on a cart pulled by oxen, and driven by Uzza and Ahio ,  a clear violation of the commands of God , who also said that they must not touch the Holy Things ( Num 4:15)
1Chr. 13:3 And let us bring again the ark of our God to us: for we enquired not at it in the days of Saul.
1Chr. 13:6 And David went up, and all Israel, to Baalah, that is, to Kirjathjearim, which belonged to Judah, to bring up thence the ark of God the LORD, that dwelleth between the cherubims, whose name is called on it.
1Chr. 13:7 And they carried the ark of God in a new cart out of the house of Abinadab: and Uzza and Ahio drave the cart.
1Chr. 13:8 And David and all Israel played before God with all their might, and with singing, and with harps, and with psalteries, and with timbrels, and with cymbals, and with trumpets.
1Chr. 13:9 ¶ And when they came unto the threshingfloor of Chidon, **Uzza put forth his hand to hold the ark; for the oxen stumbled.**
1Chr. 13:10 And the anger of the LORD was kindled against Uzza, and he smote him, because he put his hand to the ark: and there he died before God.

What we are seeing is a violation of Gods command, which at a higher level shows that Divine instructions matter and must not be taken lightly

Answer (score 0):

I believe to be charged with the task means to carry the over seeing thereof not carry literally to carryit, to bare the responsibility of it. The Holy thing could not be touched by anyone not even levites because it housed the presence of God, holiness and no man could touch God and live. He is to holy. Remember he appeared to Moses as a burning bush not as Himself. God’s presence is Holy and man could not touch God. Therefore oxen pulled it but the charge to bare and carry it ( to take care of the Ark ) was given to the Levites. After Jesus came we are now covered in His righteousness so we can be touched by God or come into His holy presence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).